# Moving an Image in circular motion based on touch events in android

Tags: android, math, transform, touch-event

I am trying to move an ImageView (not rotate). The movement is supposed to be on the edge of a circle. This circle is also an image view.

based on the onTouch, ACTION_MOVE event, I am trying to move it.

Noe the Dilema is that the use may not move the finger in a perfectly circular fashion but I would like to make sure that the image still moves around edge of this circle.

I am currently using the following inside ACTION_MOVE:

```
mCurrTempIndicator.setTranslationX(event.getX());
mCurrTempIndicator.setTranslationY(event.getY());
```

But this will not move in a perfect circle.

could someone please help.

UPDATE: code

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                        mInitialX = event.getX();
                        mInitialY = event.getY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    mEndX = event.getX();
                    mEndY = event.getY();

                    float deltaX = mEndX - mInitialX;
                    float deltaY = mEndY - mInitialY;
                    double angleInDegrees = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;

                    mInitialX = mEndX;
                    mInitialY = mEndY;

                    mCurrTempIndicator.setRotation((float)angleInDegrees);
                    mCurrTempIndicator.setTranslationX((float)(310*(Math.cos(angleInDegrees))));
                    mCurrTempIndicator.setTranslationY((float)(310*(Math.sin(angleInDegrees))));




                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    allowRotating = true;
                    break;
            }



            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. calculate the center Point of the Circle
2. get the current touch point
3. calculate the angle between center and new touch point
4. Calculate the point on the circle using angle and radius of circle (x = r * cos(angle), y = r * sin(angle)).
5. Reset the image position to the new point.

To get the angle use the below equation

```
deltaY = P2_y - P1_y
deltaX = P2_x - P1_x
angleInDegrees = arctan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / PI

//Code inside ACTION_MOVE case
mInitialX = event.getX();
mInitialY = event.getY();
float deltaX = circleCenter.x - mInitialX;
float deltaY = circleCenter.y - mInitialY;
double angleInRadian = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
PointF pointOnCircle = new PointF();
pointOnCircle.x = circleCenter.x + ((float)(circleRadius*(Math.cos(angleInRadian))));
pointOnCircle.y = circleCenter.y + ((float)(circleRadius*(Math.cos(angleInRadian))));
```

Comment: the problem is that i am not rotating the image. I am moving it along the circle so i don't want to rotate it. how do i move the image by a certain angle on the circle

Comment: thanks a lot for all the help...one last question. Since my listener is set to the imageview, getx() and gety() give me x, y relative to the image. How do i find the x,y relative to the circle. Both circle and image are children of the same parent

Comment: Add the listener to the parent of ImageView and define your circle based on the parent.

Comment: great thanks for all  the help.. btw P1-y and P1_x are the coordinates of the centre of the circle right?

Comment: ok this is not working. it is revolving not around the circle and in fact the touch point has become the centre point of rotation. I have posted the code. could u please check? i have updated the code.