# Circular motion of drawing object

Tags: java, android

Can someone help me in the formula to make the drawing object move in circular motion? I had tried to get the formula from the internet but it still not working.

```
ball.set(x_position_ball / 2 - 25
            , y_position_ball - 400
            , x_position_ball / 2 + 25
            , y_position_ball - 350);
black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawOval(ball, black);

int angle = 5;
int radius = 10;
int center_x = 300, center_y
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check out this resource [http://www.helixsoft.nl/articles/circle/sincos.htm](http://www.helixsoft.nl/articles/circle/sincos.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546897/moving-an-image-in-circular-motion-based-on-touch-events-in-android) should help, or check mine, which is rotation. It is in a res/anim folder under 'rotation.xml':

[image]